# autofill leading zero depending on length in sql (odbc on db2 w/ squirrel)

Tags: sql, db2, ibm-midrange, trim

I have a database table where the timestamps are like following:

TIME

```
85000
91000
171500
171500
```

how can I transform that into something like

```
0850
1715
...?
```

The defined length of this value is always 6, so I need to work with *trim* (I guess) in order to first identify if the time was before 10:00 or vice versa.

Cutting the value with left or right won't help right away, also, I do not have all sql-commands due to odbc to DB2 on as400.. so that is a bummer as well.

Comment: If any value is 700 then you need 0007, right?

Comment: Hi Dinesh, 

Possibly I haven't described my problem sufficiently enough, sorry for that.

My problem was, that after my first trials I always had results like 0131 instead 1315.

Comment: Okay, I try to find the solution for a long time. It's okay. Are you get it now?

Comment: Hi Dinesh,
what do you think of my solution below?

Comment: Squirrel uses JDBC, and I am able to use the full range of DB2 for i SQL commands (except Squirrel doesn't really build stored procedures properly due to not understanding statement end delimiters for DB2 for i). If you are really using ODBC with Squirrel and having trouble with some SQL statements or functions, may I suggest you get JTOpen from sourceforge.

Comment: will go for JTOpen now, thx for the hint!

Answer (score 2):

Here is another way that works:

```
left(digits(timestamp),4)
```

Note that timestamp is not really a timestamp, but a decimal(6,0) value. This will also work for times like 0015 or 0001 where you would need to concat('000000', timestamp) for your solution to work in the first hour after midnight.

Comment: Of course you're right, the content represents a certain time information as a decimal value. Thanks for sharing your approach btw, that works great and is less confusing and less prone for typos.

Answer (score 1):

I have managed now, seems to work as wanted:

```
left(right(concat('0',timestamp),6),4) as formatted_time
```

I first added a zero at the beginning:

```
concat('0',timestamp)**
```

in order to have a length of 6 also for the timestamps smaller than 10:00.
Then I grabbed all six characters from the right

```
right(concat('0',timestamp),6)
```

and finally the first 4 characters of this new result

```
left(right(concat('0',timestamp),6),4)
```

and got

```
0600
0945
1315
```

I am aware that this is not the most elegant or efficient solution. Of course I do appreciate further input.

Comment: Congrats honk77